# How to load large xml layouts faster in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, xml-layout

I have a xml layout that contains almost **60 TextViews**, **30 EditText**, **60 CheckBoxes** and some background **xml shapes** for form designing. 
Now my Activity is taking 2-3 seconds to load on lollipop with 2 GB RAM. So far I didn't have implemented anything in JAVA file.

Is there any way to load it faster? Or any mechanism that will cache the form etc? Need your suggestions, What would be the best way to load it faster?

Comment: i assume they not fit one screen so show them using for example `RecyclerView` and they will be shown as fast as a thunder

Comment: I am using scrollview and inside that multiple linear layouts. Can you show me a demo of what you are saying?

Comment: see any `RecycyclerView` example that uses more than one type of item views

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have json file that based your application form

`[
   {
      "type":"text",
      "name":"name"
   },
   {
      "type":"checkBox",
      "name":"Men"
   },
   {
      "type":"checkBox",
      "name":"Women"
   },
   {
      "type":"checkBox",
      "name":"Have Child?"
   }
]`

You need to create adapter that support two ViewType read this blog post, it will help you to figure out https://medium.com/@ruut_j/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-item-types-bce7fbd1d30e

Comment: Thanks for your time. Let me check it!